# How to refresh OG:tags for WhatsApp

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

If i update og:image or og:title of a website an rescrape the url with [facebook linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), in Facebook the data/the preview is updated.
Unfortunately i can't find a similar solution for WhatsApp.
If i repost a link with updated metadata in a WhatsApp-Chat, the preview shows the old metadata.
I am not sure, if this is a problem with local- or online-cache.

Does ne1 knows, how to refresh meta-data for WhatsApp, if
renaming the URL is not an option?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution:
If i delete all of that links in my whatsapp-chat/group-media and repost the link, the preview is refreshed and shows the new meta-data on repost.
So i guess WA caches the meta-data only local and not online like Facebook. no need for a debugger-tool for WA.
Can someone confirm?

Comment: I never inserted the link in Whatsapp, just preview it and while FB debugger shows the latest og data, WA fails to render it when I try to post/preview in a chat

Comment: I had to go to app's settings from the mobile phone settings. App -> force stop, then App -> storage -> clear cache